# Implementing a concurrent queue

Tags: java, multithreading, data-structures, concurrency, operating-system

> Implement a concurrent queue such that infinite threads can do a `peek()` operation, but only one can `poll()` and `offer()` at a certain time. In addition, if a thread is wanting to `poll()` an empty queue, it should wait until there is an item in the queue and then do a `poll()`.

```
class ConcurrentQ{
  Semaphore mutex = new Semaphore(1, true); 
  Semaphore db = new Semaphore(1, true);  
  Semaphore full = new Semaphore(0, true);
  Queue<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
  volatile int peekers = 0;

  public void push(int x){
    db.acquire(); 
    list.push(x);
    full.release();
    db.release();
  }

  //Must look at empty case
  public int pop(){
    full.acquire();
    db.acquire();
    int x = list.pop();
    db.release();
    return x;
  }

  public int peek(){
    mutex.acquire();
      if(peekers == 0){
        db.acquire();
      }
      ++peekers;
    mutex.release();

    int val = list.front();

    mutex.acquire();
      if(peekers == 1){
        db.release();
      }
      --peekers;
    mutex.release();
    return val;
  }
}
```

This is my implementation and I feel it is correct for the most part (**can someone help me check it?**). I am confused about the `pop()` method in specific. Is the use of the `full` semaphore correct?

Comment: This question seems better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Andreas, thanks !

Comment: why does your code say "push" and "pop" when the question says "offer" and "poll"?

Comment: This does not fulfill the requirement that “infinite threads can do a `peek()` operation”, as your code relies on the ability to hold the number of threads doing a `peek()` operation in an `int` variable. Besides that, the operation spends more time in mutual exclusive code than in the actual concurrent operation. A blocking queue only doing the necessary minimum is likely to be more “concurrent”. And where does this `front()` method come from? Not from the standard `Queue` interface…

Comment: Your mutexes could be better named. How about `peekers_mutex` and `queue_mutex` instead of `mutex` and `db`?

Comment: I am suspicious of your `peek()` method. Here's the problem: The way you use those mutexes, It looks like you anticipate some threads calling `peek()` while other threads are calling `push()` and `pop()`, and there's no other synchronization between them. In a single-threaded application, If I call `peek()` and then I call `pop()`, I expect to get the same value both times. But in a program that _needs_ the synchronization that's built-in to your `ConcurrentQ` class, it won't be true.  What's the use of me calling `peek()` if it doesn't necessarily return the same value as the next `pop()`?

Comment: @besmirched, if I call peek() before calling pop() then that would give the same peek() value as the pop() value

Comment: @BrijendarBakchodia, That is not true if other threads are pushing and popping at the same time:  Thread A calls `peek()`, and gets a certain value.  Then while thread A is deciding what to do next, thread B could sneak in and call `pop()`.  Finally, thread A calls `pop()`, and it gets a different value from the one that was returned by the `peek()` call.

Comment: @besmirched, yeah I see. What is the way around this? Is it just by using locks? (Read/write lock?)

Comment: @besmirched you are starting a discussion about the *use case* of this class, which is irrelevant to the *given task*, the OP tried to solve. `peek` tells you the current first value, without any guarantees. There is no requirement for such guarantees in the task description, in fact, they are implicitly denied. Since it should be possible that “infinite threads can do a `peek()` operation”, it is obvious that those threads can never assume that a subsequent `pop()` will give them that value, as at most one thread out of those infinite threads can pop it.

Comment: What?   If you are using semaphores to manage the queue, there is no need to check the queue at all - it's totally redundant?

Comment: @BrijendarBakchodia, yes, by using a lock, but in order to guarantee that thread B will not `pop()` anything from the queue in between thread A's use of `peek()` and `pop()`, thread A must lock a lock before it calls `peek()`, and keep the lock locked until after it calls `pop()`; and thread B must also lock the same lock before calling `pop()`.

Comment: @Holger, Yes. That is why I posted a comment instead of posting an answer.